# How to update eclipse via zip and keep plugins and configurations

Tags: eclipse, ide, updates, m2eclipse

I want to update my eclipse installation, but keeping my plugins and configurations. Is it possible doing it just replacing the files downloaded with the zip file?

I'm looking to correct some errors and improve performance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to upgrade it, just using the eclipse installer and installing on the current folder, now I'm testing the new installation to verify if everything is ok.

Comment: The main advantage of the _Eclipse Installer_ is a common plug-in pool for multiple installations.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, but you can

- [directly **update your existing Eclipse IDE**](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F) or
- install the plug-ins from the old installation into the new installation: ***File > Import: Install > From Existing Installation***

Comment: Every time I try to update I get an error, anyhow I managed to upgrade it, just using the eclipse installer and installing on the current folder, now I'm testing the new installation to verify if everything is ok...

Comment: Oh! I can't remember the error message exactly but it was something with eclipse couldn't find o establish communication with the repositories. 

Anyway, I found out that my pool was pointing to a different folder, I changed user on windows and dragged the shortcut from old user to the new, So eclipse config file was looking to oldUser/.p2, I copied that folder into newUser/ replace everything, and then used the eclipse installer over the old eclipse to upgrade it!

Now everything seems to be fine and working even smoother...